# redirect multiple pages with 301 htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have about 3500 pages that will change URL because I need to remove one keyword from the URL. I will submit an updated sitemap to google but I would also like to provide **htaccess 301 redirects** for a while.

old url example "http://www.domain.com/my-old-url/"
new url is "http://www.domain.com/my-url/"

old url example "http://www.domain.com/my-old-url-page/"
new url is "http://www.domain.com/my-url-page/"

Keyword that needs to be removed is "old" and repeats itself across all url's.

Having 3500 individual 301 redirect lines in my htaccess would probably slow down my server and I don't think it's wise to do.

So I am asking what would be the best way to apply these 3500 redirects?
Please provide code examples for your suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Provide some examples of old and new URLs

Comment: @anubhava examples added, thanks!

Comment: That’s an easy thing to do with a RewriteRule. Do some research on that, try some things – and then report back with your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a `RedirectMatch` rule here in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+?)-old(.*)$ /$1$2
```