# Individual 301 redirect of all pages including root (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

1. The Website example-ONE.com is relaunched at example-TWO.com
2. All subpages of example-ONE.com moved to different URLs on example-TWO.com like  example-ONE.com/product1.html to example-TWO.com/product-xyz

Problem:
Redirect 301 /product1.html https://example-TWO.com/product-xyz - for subpages works fine

but as add I redirect old root / to new https://example-TWO.com ...
example-ONE.com/product1.html - redirects to  https://example-TWO.com/product1.html
and not more https://example-TWO.com/product-xyz

What is the right way to redirect (.htaccess) individually subpages to new URLs and old root to new root?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect multiple pages with 301 htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667157/redirect-multiple-pages-with-301-htaccess)

Comment: Nope, t's completely different issue :(